# Advanced web scraping

Tags: web-scraping

I want to scrape a part of a website, lets say: www.mywebsite.com/**x1**/**x2**

The website needs login information.

You need to open **x1** first then you click on a button and **x2** will be opened as a popup window. If you close **x1** you lose access to **x2**.

I used Internet Download Manager, and I think I correctly put login information but this failed because you need **x1** to be opened when you access **x2**.

The website support JavaScript.

Comment: what is `IDM`? What tools, language do you use to request web pages?

Comment: IDM stands for the software called Internet Download Manager.

Comment: See if you can log on and **directly** access `www.mywebsite.com/x1/x2` without JavaScript (i.e. type the URL  in if you have to). This will depend if you can use a simple scraper or need a full headless browser (which will be much slower).

Comment: It is NOT possible to access directly **x2**

Comment: Even if you type the URL in? Why is it not possible? More detail, please.

Comment: When you type the URL: www.mywebsite.com/x1/x2 directly, you will be redirected to www.mywebsite.com

Comment: It's difficult to say, as you have not provided much detail, but it is possible that the site is indeed dependent on JavaScript. You could look at PhantomJS to drive a real JS-supporting headless browser. There are driver libraries for Phantom for a number of scripting languages, such as PHP.

Comment: @halfer, Thank you, PhantomJS seems interesting, I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: If PHP is acceptable in your case, consider [Spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/spiderling) as a driver. I've used the related PHPUnit component [in this project](https://github.com/halfer/awooga-app/blob/master/test/browser/classes/TestCase.php) for testing JS-dependent pages.

Answer (score 0):

IDM (after I've looked at) is for downloading, not for regular web scraping. Why not to use a special [web scraping software](https://www.google.ru/search?q=web%20scraping%20softwar&oq=web%20scraping%20softwar&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.262j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)? Most of them support logging in and complicated html and [js-driven pages](https://webscraping.pro/javascript-protected-content-scrape/) scrape. Seems to me your case is not a pure html page but a js-stuffed web page.